# Get value of columns in Excel

Tags: excel

[image]

Here i got a table in Excel. But how can I make these columns calculate in the 4th column the average from the ABC colums in front of it? I know how I can do it manually: AVERAGE(A1:A3) per column but that takes way too long.. Someone know a shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct formula to measure averages for the 3 columns to a cell's left is `AVERAGE(A1:C1)`. Beneficially, we don't have to enter it for each row. Instead, enter it once in row 1. Next, if you hover your mouse over the lower right corner of the cell, the mouse cursor will turn into a small icon that looks like a t. Once this happens, click and drag the formula down as far as you'd like.